# How to retrieve a list of unique paths between two nodes in my neo4j graph using cypher?

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

So I have a directed graph in neo4j that has two node types, say A and B. Basically at the top A points to many B's, each of which point to many A's, recursively down a way. Something like this:

A1 -> B1, B2, B3

B1 -> A3, A4, A7

B2 -> A5, A6, A8

A3 -> B3

A4 -> B3

A5 -> B3

B3 -> A9

Anyway, taking in two different A's, I want to run a query to get out all unique paths between those two A's. So given A1 and A9 from above, I would want the following as output:

A1 -> B1 -> A3 -> B3 -> A9,

A1 -> B1 -> A4 -> B3 -> A9,

A1 -> B2 -> A5 -> B3 -> A9,

A1 -> B3 -> A9

If possible, I'd like to strip out the B's from within the same query as well (since they aren't necessary for this specific case), so the end result would be the following:

A1 -> A3 -> A9,

A1 -> A4 -> A9,

A1 -> A5 -> A9,

A1 -> A9

If not, I can do that manually after although within the query would be better obviously. How exactly would I form that query?

So far I have something like this:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, object> {{a1.toString(), a1}, {a2.toString(), a2}};

var query = _graphClient.Cypher
    .Start(dic)
    .Match(String.Format("p={0}-[*]->{1}", a1.toString(), a2.toString()))
    //I don't know what goes here exactly... .Return(something)
    .Results;

return query.Single();
```

I'm thinking I need to do something with multiple cypher queries in order to strip out the B's. Maybe something like using this as an intermediary and applying that to any depth:

```
a1-[]->b-[]->a2
return a1, a2;
```

Any help would be amazing! Thank you ahead of time!!!

**Update**

With Christophe Willemsen's comment and this post ([Neo4j .NET Client - Getting a Path from a Node to its Root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659614/neo4j-net-client-getting-a-path-from-a-node-to-its-root)), I was able to get the following c# code which does everything but the removing of B's from the path:

```
var query = _graphClient.Cypher
    .Match("p = (a2:A)-[*]->(a1:A)")
    //Where and AndWhere's for matching a1 and a2 as necessary
    .Return<IEnumerable<A>>("nodes(p)")
    .OrderByDescending("length(p)")
    .Results
    .SelectMany(result => new List<List<A>> {result.ToList()});

return query.ToList();
```

If anyone knows how to specify to nodes(p) to only return A's, that should do it. I can simply iterate through each path removing the B's, but that's not terribly efficient if there are a lot of them especially if there's some nifty cypher way to do it. Thanks for the help so far though!

Comment: The cypher to filter `nodes (p)` with a label would be `FILTER (n IN NODES (p) WHERE n:A)`. Not sure how you do that in the fluent cypher client, if you have to use a `.Filter` method or if you can just add the cypher filter function to the string you pass as argument to `.Return`.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe use the allShortestPaths algorithm together with distinct like this :

```
MATCH (a:A { name:'A1' }),(aa:A { name:'A8' }), p = allShortestPaths((a)-[*]-(aa))

RETURN DISTINCT (p), collect(nodes(p)) AS x

ORDER BY length(p) DESC 

LIMIT 5
```

I've setup a neo4j console as sandbox available here : http://console.neo4j.org/?id=pjf2qg

I struggle of how to be able to remove the B nodes from the results btw

### Update

I ended up to extract only the A labelized nodes from paths :

```
MATCH (a:A {name:'A1'}),(aa:A {name:'A8'}),
p = allShortestPaths((a)-[*]-(aa))
WITH DISTINCT(p) as pths, COLLECT(nodes(p)) as x
UNWIND(x) as u
WITH FILTER(s IN u WHERE 'A' IN labels(s)) AS zz, pths as paths
RETURN paths, zz
```

Chris

Comment: `nodes (p)` already returns a collection, if you `collect` it again, you have a (single element) collection of the collection of all nodes in `p`. If you don´t collect it you also don´t have to unwind before filtering, but you can filter right away. `a:A` is also a valid predicate, so you can test that way instead of for the string representation of the label in `labels`. Here´s what it could look like: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=z6lqc3

Answer (score 0):

My first answer was edited with a working query.

BTW when trying to find this query, I found the following :

When trying to filter the collection of nodes(p), without the unwind, the identifier is not treated as a Node but as a collection, I don't know if it is the expected behavior :

The following query will fail saying that the identifier s is a collection and a Node is expected

```
MATCH (a:A {name:'A1'}),(aa:A {name:'A8'}),
p = allShortestPaths((a)-[*]-(aa))
WITH p as paths, COLLECT(nodes(p)) as x
WITH filter(s IN x WHERE 'A' IN labels(s)) AS zz
RETURN zz
```